# Why this function always returns zero?

Tags: c#, function

This is the function:

```
private decimal? CalculateMe(int? kat0, int? kat1, int? kat2, int? numberOfPlants)
{
    if (numberOfPlants == null || numberOfPlants == 0 || kat0 == null || kat1 == null || kat2 == null)
        return null;

    return ((kat1 + kat2 * 2) / (numberOfPlants * 2)) * 100;
}
```

This function always returns zero! Even if an explicit cast is written `Convert.ToDecimal`, the function returns zero.

```
return Convert.ToDecimal(((kat1 + kat2 * 2) / (numberOfPlants * 2)) * 100);
```

Comment: Can you provide some samples? Using `/` on an `int` with an outcome of less than 0 will always result in 0.

Comment: Just pass any values by your choice.

Comment: You know in this (kat1 + kat2 * 2) the "kat2 * 2" will be done first.  I would add parenthesis to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the operator `/` with two `int`s as operands always performs an [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Of_integers).

If you want to perform a real division, you need to convert the operands to a non-integer numeric type (`float`, `double`, `decimal`). In other words, you have to perform the conversion *before* the division happens, not afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast each of your operands to get that to work, i.e.:

```
  return ((decimal)(kat1 + kat2 * 2) / (decimal)(numberOfPlants * 2)) * 100;
```

Comment: No you don't. All you need to do is cast ONE of the variables as *decimal*, *float* or *double*. The rest will be implicitly cast.

Answer (score 0):

You operate on integer.
Ex : 1/3 = 0 (if 1 and 3 are `int`).

You should use others types (decimal or float, etc).